# Google Custom search API returning Access Not Configured (iOS app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-custom-search

Read through all of the similar posts and couldn't find a solution.

NSURLConnection:

```
<NSURLConnection: 0x178004020> { request: <NSURLRequest: 0x178003ff0> { URL: https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[API_KEY_SPECIFIC_TO_IOS_BUNDLE_ID]&cx=[SEARCH_ENGINE_ID_FOR_CUSTOM_SEARCH_ENGINE]&q=[SEARCH_STRING] } }
```

response :

```
{
    error =     {
        code = 403;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = usageLimits;
                message = "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.";
                reason = accessNotConfigured;
            }
        );
        message = "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.";
    };
}
```

I went to the Google Developers Console and explored the Custom Search API for my project.  It corresponds to this URL:

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/[PROJECT ID]/apiui/api/customsearch/method/search.cse.list
```

It successfully ran and showed this request (along with the correct results):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=[SEARCH_STRING]&cx=[SEARCH_ENGINE_ID_FOR_CUSTOM_SEARCH_ENGINE]&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
```

So I conclude from that success:

1. [SEARCH_ENGINE_ID_FOR_CUSTOM_SEARCH_ENGINE] value is correct
2. [SEARCH_ENGINE_ID_FOR_CUSTOM_SEARCH_ENGINE] value is associated to my project, since I "explored" it from within my project

I verified that the Custom Search API is indeed turned ON

I also verified on the API Access page, underneath that project, that I am using the correct API Key and iOS Apps (bundle ID) listed in the Simple API Access section.

I am not sure where to go from here to troubleshoot this and get it working.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Here is a prominent guide for all you need to make it work http://stackoverflow.com/a/27039037/656600

Answer (score 1):

Double check if your Google Developers console show as the below screen (for your own module, mine is google map).

[image]

[image]

If you are sure that everything is correct on the Developer console side and you still see the error, Delete it from the console and make a new one and try again. Yes, this is weird but I have faced the similar issue before that and I solved it by **delete and recreate**.

Comment: Hi Ricky.  Thanks for the assistance.  I deleted the credentials and still no love.  I'll try emailing the contact you provided.  I'll report back with what I find.

Comment: No problem. I hope Brett is able to help you further then.

Comment: Haven't heard back.  Thanks for your valiant attempt!

Comment: No problem. I hope that you can somehow find a way to get it working. May be you can try the Google Group like https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-ajax-search-api and see if you have any luck.